# Where to save a long JSON string as a variable in android application

Tags: android, json

I have a very long string (5000 lines more or less) which is a JSON that I will need to get data from. In this json there is a big array of data that I want to read as the user uses my app to display particular information.

Since the JSON array is not likely to change, I tought it would be better, resources-wise, to keep it stored and served with the .apk rather than initiating a new HTTP connection to my server.

What is the best practice to store such a large variable?

Comment: check my answer hope this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the data inside a Text file and put it inside the assets folder of android app. When you need the data, just open the file and read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `JSON` data into a `File` and retrieve later when needed.

**Store `JSON` into `File`:**

```
String fileName = "yourFile.json";
String jsonResponse = json.toString(); // here json is JSONObject or JSONArray

// Store
saveJSONData(this, jsonResponse);

public void saveJSONData(Context context, String mJsonResponse) {
    try {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName);
        file.write(mJsonResponse);
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error in Writing: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

**Retrieve `JSON` from `File`:**

```
String fileName = "yourFile.json";

// Retrieve
String jsonResponse = getJSONData(this);

public String getJSONData(Context context) {
    try {
        File f = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName);
        //check whether file exists
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        return new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error in Reading: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~